# PHP CURL (Failed to connect to 192.168.168.85 port 8080: Connection timed out)

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am using PHP cURL to get the response back from the api (192.168.168.85:8080) with GET request.
When i run the code in localhost. Everything runs perfect(response is obtained) but the same code does not work from the live server.

**Here's my code**

```
        $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $sendHere//$sendhere is (192.168.168.85:8080?along with some query strings)
    ));

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);

    $test=curl_error($curl);
    echo json_encode([$test,$resp]);
```

Every time the response is false along with Error 7. Failed to connect

I have done a lot of research and gone through all the question that have been asked and found that this could be because of proxy or port other than 80 but still cannot figure out how to solve the issue.

**Please help**

Comment: Any chance there's a firewall in place? If you ssh into the live server, can you ping the ip successfully? Can you pull any apache/nginx error logs from the api server?

Comment: It working from one place and not from another smells strongly of a firewall configuration issue, i.e., you need to allow traffic from the "live server."

Comment: @varlogtim allowing traffic. How can i do so ?

Comment: What firewall is running on the "live server?" If it is a linux server and iptables, try `iptables -L -v -n` to show the rules. Please provide more information about what the "live server" is.

Comment: Is your localhost in the same network as the live server?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil no it's 127.0.0.1 and port 80 running on local machine

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's most likely a server or network configuration issue, not a problem in the PHP script.

Comment: @SelvesanMalakar: well I did't mean your computer's loop address, but the address of computer's network interface.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil oh sorry! No it is not using my computer's network interface address

Comment: @SelvesanMalakar: okay, another try: Address `192.168.168.85` is a private network address, which cannot be routed via internet. If you can access the address from your computer and not from the server, it could mean that the server is in another network, which has no routes to the `192.168.168.85` address. But as @Barmar pointed out, this is more of a network configuration issue than a PHP problem.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Well i am using FortiClient SSLVPN with server address, username and password to connect to this address(192.168.168.85).
How is the it(request/response) possible when i am on my xampp localhost

Comment: @SelvesanMalakar: Do I understand correctly that your computer (the one running _localhost_) is connected to VPN via FortiClient?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil yes it has to be connected to VPN via FortiClient inorder to make the request through localhost as well as through live server

Comment: @SelvesanMalakar: so the live server is connected to the VPN via FortiClient as well?

Comment: @SelvesanMalakar: then you need to check the firewall on the server, maybe it does not permit outgoing connections on port 8080.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil thankyou for providing with your valuable time i totally appreciate it. I am a bit rookie here so i will have to do some research on checking the firewall on the server thanks for you help once again i will comment if i have any problem

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Hellor there i have added the port 8080 at the whm still the same problem